# Can you roast vegetables before freezing instead of blanching?

Tags: storage-method

I don't like the texture of green beans after blanching and freezing, I'd like to know if you can roast them in the oven instead of blanching.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, however they will suffer the same problems with texture as you find with the blanched beans. This is because it is the cooking part that is affecting the texture, not the freezing.

You can also freeze green-beans fresh without blanching. All you need to do is rinse, slice (if you like), then freeze. They may change color when cooked after thawing to a more brownish green, but the texture is less mushy in my opinion.

Comment: do you mean "it is the freezing part that is affecting the texture, not the cooking"?

Comment: No - the cooking breaks down the cell wall and makes them soft. Freezing does this too to some extent, but it depends on how fast they freeze and a few other things. Blanching is primarily about preserving color - it is par-cooking essentially, so when you pull them out of the freezer and then re-cook they go soft because they have been partially cooked already.